# Powermail: Sending only fieldsets with valid fields in it

Tags: typo3, typo3-4.5, typo3-extensions

We have a powermail form with a huge amount of fieldsets and each fieldset containing 3 fields:

- 1x "typo3 pagecontent" (with a reference to a text&image-element)
- 2x "select box" (drop-down)

The requirement is that only those fieldsets are sent in which is at least one valid field.

So we managed the simple validation for "filled/not filled" with the pipe-solution, which means, that the first item is followd by a pipe | - and if this item is selected, the whole field is invalid and will not be sent. Example (selection items):

- none |
- value 1
- value 2

The effect is, that when the form is sent, we get a list with the filled fields, all not-filled-fields are missing - that's okay.

**Here's the real problem:** 
If I want to set a title (as text-field) to a fieldset, for that I can see what "article" it is, when it's filled, then this title-field is also shown when no select-field is valid (= not filled).

**Here's the real question:**
Does anyone have an idea how I could manage that the whole fieldset is not sent when the fields in it are "not valid" (= not filled).

*Additional Info: I already tried powermail-conditions - but this is more a fearure to handle database data via ajax.*

Comment: Which version of powermail are you using?

Comment: We are using powermail 1.6.10 on TYPO3 4.5 LTS - we can't switch to newer versions because of some dependencies which I don't know at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I found a *half* solution:

Template Constant-Editor: Powermail(43)
plugin.powermail.markerALL.hideLabel > check

Select-values will also be ignored, when the "not valid" value is only a pipe | (not "-|" or "...|").

Too bad that this is not well documented.

Comment: If this is the real solution, please accept it as community wiki (click the check sign below the counter).

Comment: No, sorry, it's not the full solution - I still need to configure that the fieldset is only sent when all fields are valid. with this "half" solution I can handle the validity of selects - but if I have a "show some text" field (which I need as title because the T3-content-refs will not be shown in the mail) - it will always be valid - or: seen or not seen in the mail by manual activation.

I think there will be a scripted modification. :(